# running bat file using windows scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduling

i wanted to run a .bat file in windows task scheduler, so i opened it, added a new task, browsed to the bat file, and... nothing happened. so i changed the timing to see if it'll run, and it didn't. next i right-clicked on the task and chose "run"- it didn't run. the file itself is only one line, basically backups a folder to a another location. it runs fine when not in the scheduler. 
what can be done?
thank you

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question, your .bat file is running fine, just need to know how to use it in scheduler. Might be better asked on superuser.com

Comment: This is a question for Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not give batch file directly as a task. Instead you should use

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C <completepathtobatchfile> <argstobatchfileifany>
```

the complete path to cmd.exe may vary in your case depending on which drive you installed OS and which version you are using.

Comment: ok then. what does the /C do, btw?

thank you for your help

Comment: /C will make cmd.exe to exit after executing the specified command. Here it is your batch file. Else, cmd.exe will not exit.

Comment: it wont run.
in "run" text field i wrote: cmd.exe /C k:\backup.bat in the "start in" i wrote: k:\
and the task will not run.

Comment: Try giving full path to cmd.exe.See this for step-by-step details.
http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm